# pass arguments to php build in server

Tags: php, server

I am using the PHP built-in web server, like `php -S localhost:8000`, and I would like to pass to the php script some arguments.

I tried with `$argv`, but it returns `null`.

I tried with `getopt()` but it returns `false`.

Is it possible to pass arguments to the PHP script when using the built-in web server? If so, how?

Comment: Warning
This web server was designed to aid application development. It may also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.

Comment: @JayBlanchard this is not a duplicate because this is about the built in web server, not a generic php script

Comment: Built-in web server? Built-in to what?

Comment: @Daan thank for the warning. I know that and I'm usign it for a simple personal project

Comment: @JayBlanchard http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Ah - it has been so long since I've ever seen it mentioned I thought it had gone away.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Please, can you remove the duplicate request, then?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a need for something similar to this today (CLI script that needed to "fork" itself off to handle a couple of HTTP requests), and came up with the following Linux-only solution.

You need to invoke the dev server using something like this:

```
php -S localhost:8000 index.php -- your 'command arguments' here
```

The code below (living in `index.php` or whatever your router is), then reads the full process command line from `/proc/self/cmdline` and discards items from it until it reaches the `--` marker.

With the example above, this would result in an `$argc` of `4` and an `$argv` of `["/path/to/index.php", "your" "command arguments" "here"]`.

```
$cmdline = file_get_contents('/proc/self/cmdline');
$argv = str_getcsv($cmdline, "\0");
while (true) {
    $arg = array_shift($argv);
    if ($arg === null || $arg === '--') {
        // Stick whatever on the start to align with normal $argv
        array_unshift($argv, __FILE__);
        if ($arg !== null) {
            // Remove extra empty arg at the end
            array_pop($argv);
        }
        break;
    }
}
$argc = count($argv);

print('<pre>');
var_dump($argc, $argv);
print('</pre>');
```

Comment: This doesn't work for PHP 8.1.6. argc is 0 argv is null